# basic java parameter passing, computation inside a method

Tags: java

i have initialized a variable value and an inputted value.. netbeans is giving me errors.. can anyone please point out the problem with my code

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
        static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        static double maxLoad = 500;
        static double currLoad;
        static double loadInput = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String cpNumber;


        System.out.println("Enter Cellphone Number");
        cpNumber = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter load to be bought");
        loadInput = sc.nextDouble();

        computeLoad(maxLoad, loadInput);
        System.out.println(currLoad);
    }

    public static double computeLoad(double x, double y) {
        double z = 0;
        x - y = z;
    return z;
    }
}
```

i got another error. it keeps returning 0..

Comment: `x - y = z;` Assignment is right to left.

Comment: `x - y = z;` invalid assignment
write as `z = x - y;`

Comment: it fixed it. but why is that when i code through notepad and compile through cmd it works but not with netbeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1) When you assign a variable, put the variable on the left, and the expression on the right

2) Currently, the return value of `computeLoad` is ignored. Even when you fix your function to compile, it is not going to work, because `currLoad` that you print would remain initialized to its default value.

You have two options to fix this:

- Change the call to `currLoad = computeLoad(maxLoad, loadInput);`, or
- Change the `computeLoad` to `void`, and assign `currLoad` right there.

Answer (score 2):

it should be:

```
public static double computeLoad(double x, double y) {
        return x- y;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x - y = z;
```

This is wrong. Assignment has to be **left to right**.
like : `z = x - y;`

Answer (score 1):

`x - y = z;` is not a valid Java statement. The assignment operator (`=`) evaluates the right operand (which may be any kind of expression, method call, literal and soon) and assigns it to the left operand (which has to be an identifier).

`z = x - y;` would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this:
`x - y = z`

Because assignment works right to left.
`z = x - y`

Your code should be the following:

```
public static double computeLoad(double x, double y) {
    double z = 0;
    z = x - y;
    return z;
}
```